# Self made iterator with range checking

Tags: c++, inheritance, iterator

This is a exercise I have to solve for school, so please give me no complete solutions, just hints ;-)

The exercise is the following:

- Implement an iterator that encapsulates another iterator (i.e., a sequence) and that performs range checking
- The iterator is initialized with the first and last element of the sequence
- If the iterator points to the first element and is decreased OR if the iterator points to the last element and is increased signal an error – choose an appropriate form of signaling the error

First I wanted to inherit iterator of vector container, then I got this (just a part of my "solution", but I realized that this is crappy and stopped...):

```
template <typename T>
class myIter : std::vector<T>::iterator
{
public:
    myIter( typename std::vector<T>::iterator start,
        typename std::vector<T>::iterator end,
        typename std::vector<T>::iterator pos,
        bool behaviour=false) : s(start), e(end), p(pos), beh(behaviour)
        {overflowFlag = false;};
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator & operator++();
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator & operator--();
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator operator++(int);
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator operator--(int);
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator & operator+=(int);
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator & operator-=(int);
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator operator+(int);
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator operator-(int);
    myIter & operator=(const myIter&) = delete;
    T operator*(){ return *p;};
    bool getFlag() {return overflowFlag;};
private:
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator s, e, p;
    bool beh;
    bool overflowFlag; // is set if beh = false. otherwise exception;
};
```

So I realized that I do not really inherit from vector iterator (I do, but I do not make use of it). What is the easiest way to use functionality of standard iterator, but implement a range check "on top"? If range is violated I can either throw an exception or I set an "errorflag" (specified by boolean "beh") but this should not be a problem to implement.

Comment: Note that you, in general, **cannot** inherit from `std::vector<T>::iterator` because this type may be `T*` which isn't a class type. You also don't _want_ to inherit from this type as it isn't intended for inheritance. You actually want to contain the iterator type (and it probably should be a template parameter to your own class type in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inheriting from the wrapped iterator type, I think it would be much easier to just store three iterators (`begin`, `end` and `current`) and implements the methods that are required for your particular iterator that does bound checking (increment, decrement) and just delegate to the wrapped `current` iterator the others.

As you've seen, you don't really use the container type, nor its iterator, so you could even pass the iterator type to your template class.

```
template < typename T, typename Iter >
class bound_checked_iterator {
 public:
  bound_checked_iterator(Iter begin, Iter end)
  : begin_(begin), end_(end), current_(begin) {}

  // implements the different methods
  bound_checked_iterator operator++();
  bound_checked_iterator operator--();
  bound_checked_iterator operator++(int);
  bound_checked_iterator operator--(int);

  T& operator *();
  const T& operator *() const;

 bool operator ==(bound_checked_operator const& other) const;
 bool operator !=(bound_checked_operator const& other) const;

 private:
  Iter begin_, end_, current_;
};
```

The methods that you need to implement for your iterator are:

- pre- and post-increment
- pre- and post-decrement
- dereference operator
- equality and inequality comparison

You can get a full list [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/).

As [@Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) mentioned in comments, you don't even need to pass the data type to the template, but you can use `std::iterator_traits<Iter>` to deduce it:

```
template < typename Iter >
class bound_checked_iterator {
 public:
  bound_checked_iterator(Iter begin, Iter end)
  : begin_(begin), end_(end), current_(begin) {}

  // ...
  typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::reference operator*();

  // ...
};
```

Comment: Note that `bound_checked_iterator` doesn't need `T` as it can be retrieved from `std::iterator_traits<Iter>`.

Comment: Implemented it this way, this works like a charm. Thanks! With this solution I can cover containers, strings and character arrays...

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to add behavior on top of any arbitrary iterator type. The class you're writing will be generic but will defer most of its actual "iterator-ness" to its template parameter: let's call that `I` for "iterator".

Wherever you've used `std::vector<T>::iterator`, instead use plain `I`. (When you're reasoning about your code, it may help to mentally replace `I` with a concrete type. For example, when iterating over a `char[]` array, `I` would be `char*`.)

The basic skeleton of your class will look like:

```
template <typename I>
class myIter
{
public:
    myIter(I start, I end, I pos);
private:
    I s, e, p;
};
```

In the various mutators (`operator++`, `--`, etc.) you will check `p` against `s` and `e` to make sure it stays within those bounds.